# Dynamic list from form

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I have a form on my website.
This form is pushed to an C# object with razor forms.

The problem is that I have multiple items of the same kind kind, so i have multiple Decision.Title and multiple Decision.description.

"Decision" is a list object, but the problem is i don't know how to make it dynamically. 
This means i have to write for each form item:

Report.Decisions[0].Title
Example:

```
<div data-decision class="box box--less-padding">
            <label class="form-item col-md-12">
                <span>Titel </span>
                <input asp-for="Report.Decisions[0].Title" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Indtast titel" />
            </label>
            <label class="form-item col-md-12">
                <span>Beslutning </span>
                <textarea asp-for="Report.Decisions[0].Description"name="decision" value=" " placeholder="indtast beslutning"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>
```

My model:

`public List<Decision> Decisions { get; set; }`

Is there a way I don't have to write [0], [1] and so on for each identical item? So I can just push it into the list, and the list handles it automatically?.

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm still new at C#

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

@foreach will be there where you can loop through Report.Decisions, this is .net mvc. I think it should be same in core mvc

Comment: Yes seems like a good call, but how do i make that foreach when the action is happening on submit? do i make it in my controller or in my html?

Answer (score 0):

You should not postback lists of data.

Best you can divide the process, make a controller which handles the editting of your Decisions individually and make a controller which handles the report. Within the view of your rapport you make a @Html.Partial call to the edit view of the decision. Something like:

/Views/Raports/Index.cshtml:

```
@model myproject.models.Raport

@foreach (var decision in Model.Decisions)
{
    <div>@Html.Partial("/Views/Decisions/Edit.cshtml", decision)</div>
}

<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('AddDecision').show();" value="Add" />

<div id="AddDecision" style="display: none;">
    @Html.Partial("/Views/Decisions/Edit.cshtml", new Decision() { RaportId = Model.Id })
</div>
```

/Views/Decisions/Edit.cshtml:

```
@model myproject.models.Decision

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Decisions", new { id = Model.Id })) 
{
    <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.RaportId)
        @Html.EditorFor(a => a.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(a => a.Description)
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
}
```

DecisionsController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, int raportid, string name, string description){
    var item = db.Decisions.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
    if (item != null)
    {
        // edit it
    }
    else 
    {
        // add it
    }
}
```

I wrote this code from my memory so sorry for any errors.

You can also generate controller/views based on your models, this will make these partial pages for you. Add a new controller than choose entity framework generated template.

Comment: Oh thank you for the quick answer, but will this bind when the way i add more of the Desicion element is on a click event? 

It works by a person wants to add one or more decisions and clicks the button. Then there are two more inputs of the same kind. If you understand? :)

Comment: No I didn't add the submit button, it should go into the edit view, inside your form. You can add a record by showing a "edit.cshtml" partial with a new record. If you don't want submit buttons you can hook up javascript and handle the submit async.

Comment: Oh but i'm not talking about the submit button. ok 1 sec i'll try to explain

Comment: I have this form, which is empty. 
- inside this from is there a button where you can add more decision fields if you want to write more decisions as a user.
- these new added fields should also be pushed into my object on submit. 
==== my question ==== 
how do i bind these new elements to my object and can i add them dynamically to my list

Comment: First of all, you don't bind, it's not webforms. All you have is controllers for putting querystrings into models and razor pages for putting models into html. Second, about the adding of a record, when you add a partial view for a new record @Html.Partial("/Views/Decisions/Edit.cshtml", new Decision()) and submit it to your /Decisions/Edit controller, you can see it wants to edit ID 0, which doesn't exists, so its a create.

Comment: okay nice so you suggest i make it as a partial and then add the partial on click. 
becuase it is working fine when i just static creates the list with the [1] [2 ] and so on in the asp-forms

Comment: Well, I can't really look into your data model, but I think that is right. Except for the last bit. When you write [0] something is wrong, the array should be empty, because you are adding the first item to the list. Doesn't your code break on a empty list?

Comment: I updated it, and I'm also off, you should be able to get my point by now. Otherwise read again.

Comment: No it does not, i found a solution for it by added a new input and then setting the name with Decision.Name[index] and then when i submit it can now read it. It's a hacky solution but it works.

Comment: You should try to understand what I'm trying to teach you here. If you get this, everything will get much easier. This is basicly all I do when making mvc websites. Except I usually do the submitting and loading though javascript. If you get this, frameworks like react will also be easier to understand.

Comment: but i dont want my submit in my partial :)